# Creating a web application (Java servlet) in Netbeans using Maven

Tags: maven, servlets, netbeans, windows-7

I have a web application, which consists of Java servlets and JSPs, I'm trying to get working in Netbeans as a Maven project. I got it working in Linux already, as well as in Netbeans, but as a regular Web project, not as a Maven project, which is required for work.

Tomcat appears to be working because when I click the Run button, my index.jsp will come up, but when I attempt to access my HelloServlet, it gives me:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class test.HelloServlet
type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class test.HelloServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class test.HelloServlet
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.HelloServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`
```

Here's my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DisplayDeleteForm</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.DisplayDeleteForm</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/helloServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.DisplayAddForm</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/displayAddForm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>submit</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.SubmitForm</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>submit</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/submitForm</url-pattern>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DisplayDeleteForm</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/displayDeleteForm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm pretty sure it's something about how I have my folders organized and files stored, but I can't see it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Devin

Comment: please edit the question and post the web.xml, also make sure that you have the test.HelloServlet class in your project.

Comment: The web.xml has been added. And as far as I can tell, the test.HelloServlet class is there, unless I'm missing some little setting.

Comment: ok, check the web.xml looks fine. Check if the class file is in the folder WEB-/INF/classes... I think the java servlet files aren't being deployed to the webapp folder.

Comment: I'm getting an Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class test.HelloServlet) error when I move an old HelloServlet.class version into the WEB-INF/classes/test folder, but I don't know how to get a current version. I'd have thought NetBeans would create one for me automatically.

Comment: It works. I didn't realize it was putting the .class files in a totally different place than expected. Rather than in my WEB-INF/classes/test folder, Maven had made a source package within the Web Pages folder and put them there. So I also had to change the package name where it was being stored.

Comment: ok, cool that you could make it work